# Cant save model in Sequelize and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to save some data from a form using Sequelize. When I post my form I get error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

server.js

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(flash());

//template engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use('/', routes);
// app.use('/user', user);

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

www

```
#!/usr/bin/env mode

var debug = require('debug')('entreeapp')
var app = require('../server');
var models = require('../model');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//server running
models.sequelize.sync({
    force: true
}).then(function () {
    var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
        console.log('The magic is happening on port '+server.address().port);
    });
});
```

index.js route

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
  var name = req.body.name;
  var lastName = req.body.lastName;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var gender = req.body.gender;
  var cellNumber = req.body.cellNumber;
  var password = req.body.password;
  models.User.build({name: name, lastName: lastName, email: email, gender: gender, cellNumber: cellNumber, password: password})
      .save();
});
```

There are values coming back from the form though. attached is a screenshot of intellij debugger.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your express config? And what does the debugger show when you open `req.body`?

Comment: I have added my config, when I open req.body it displays the attributes coming from the form with their values